# syntax error near unexpected token `|'

Tags: openssl

http://qiita.com/yutori_enginner/items/de808277cdd9e7ac32f0

上記のURLを参考にFacebookの`hash key`（リリース用）を設定しようとしたのですが、ターミナルに`keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`と入力すると、`syntax error near unexpected token`|'というエラーが返ってきてしまいます。色々と調べてみてもどうすればいいのか分かりません。どうすればリリース用の`hash key`を出力することができるでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ターミナルに以下のように入力していないでしょうか？

```
$ keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

`<RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS>` と `<RELEASE_KEY_PATH>` は自分の環境に合わせて変更する必要があります。
リリース版ではなくデバッグ版になりますがキーストアは、通常 Android 開発をする際には OSX 環境の場合 `~/.android/debug.keystore` に生成されており、エイリアスに `androiddebugkey` 、パスワードに `android` が設定されています。

そのため、ターミナルには以下のように入力する必要があります

```
$ keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

実行するとパスワードを求められるので、 `android` を入力してください。
リリース版で行う際はリリース用のキーを作成しキーストアのパス、エイリアスおよびパスワードを適切に入力してください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。<RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS>と<RELEASE_KEY_PATH>にそれぞれリリース用のキーを入力するとhash keyが出力されました。誠にありがとうございました。